# Entity Framework 6 - Updating the database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, entity-framework-6

I'm having problems with one of my 'edit' pages in a new MVC app. I have a 'create' method which creates a room, and adds a CreatedDate using DateTime.Now.

The problem I'm having is that when I edit this entry, it clears that CreatedDate if I don't specify it. If I do specify it (as shown below) then it adds the current DateTime.Now (so it's effectively a modified date).

How do I change my method so that it only updates the RoomTypeID and Description, and leaves the existing CreatedDate intact?

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "ID,RoomTypeID,Description")] Room room, int propertyId)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            room.ID = Guid.NewGuid();
            room.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
            room.PropertyID = propertyId;
            db.Room.Add(room);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I don't understand you but with you want do update why not do:

```
 Room room = db.Room.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == yourId);
if(room!=null){
  room.RoomTypeID = X;
  room.Description = Y;
  db.Room.Attach(room);
  db.Entry(room).State = EntityState.Modified;
  db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Would i need to do that inside my if (ModelState.IsValid) block?

Answer (score 1):

From what you have explained it looks like your trying to use the Create Method for updating objects. You need to have a separate ActionResult for updating an existing object.

I'm going to assume a room belongs to a Property and a Property has many rooms in which you want to be able to edit.

You should use input models which are basically DTO (Data Transfer Objects) that are not identical to the entities that your updating. Instead, they only hold those properties that you allow to be editable.

Entitiy Properties like `Id` and `DateCreated`, should never be altered, so they dont belong on the inputModel.

```
 [HttpPost]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 public async Task<ActionResult> Update( RoomInputModel roomInputModel, int roomId, int propertyId)
 {
       if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

         var room = db.Room.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == roomId && x.PropertyID == propertyId);

      if(room!= null)
      {

      // Populate existing room from the input model

        room.Description = roomInputModel.Description;
        room.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now();

        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");

       }                          
 }
```